# Calculating coefficients for least squares [cross-posted from CrossValidated]

Tags: 3d, least-squares

In [this blog](http://www.aerith.net/misao/report/seiichi/master/970917-english/node3.html), this author says to calculate the coefficients for the equation $$
Flat(x, y) = A + Bx + Cy + Dx^2 + Ey^2 + Fxy
$$ using least squares.

I found [this PDF](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~balling/FEtools/doc_files/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf) that shows how to do the calculation for $$
z = Ax + By + C
$$ using a matrix solution to linear equations as follows: $$
\left[ \matrix{
\sum_{i=1}^m x^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_i \cr
\sum_{i=1}^m x_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y_i \cr
\sum_{i=1}^m x_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y_i & \sum_{i=1}^m 1 \cr
} \right]
\left[ \matrix {A \cr B \cr C \cr} \right] =
\left[ \matrix {\sum_{i=1}^m x_iz_i \cr \sum_{i=1}^m y_iz_i \cr \sum_{i=1}^m z_i \cr} \right]
$$

I would like to extend this to calculate my required equation. What are the matrix values that I need?

**UPDATE**

By "reverse engineering" two examples given in [the PDF](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~balling/FEtools/doc_files/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf), I came up with this answer:
$$
\left[ \matrix{
\sum_{i=1}^m x_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x^3_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x^2_iy_i \cr
\sum_{i=1}^m y_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x^2_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y^3_i & \sum_{i=1}^m  x_iy^2_i \cr
\sum_{i=1}^m 1 & \sum_{i=1}^m x_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m y^2_i & \sum_{i=1}^m x_iy_i \cr
} \right]
\left[ \matrix {A \cr B \cr C \cr D \cr E \cr F \cr} \right] =
\left[ \matrix {\sum_{i=1}^m x_iz_i \cr \sum_{i=1}^m y_iz_i \cr \sum_{i=1}^m z_i \cr} \right]
$$
The "order" of the terms in the matrix are not in the same pattern as in the original matrix above, but I wanted to preserve the $flat$ equation order.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with your answer.

[image]

Comment: Mine was a stab in the dark :-) . It's been many years since I took linear algebra. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We are given a list of pixel locations $(x_i, y_i)$, for $i = 1, \ldots, m$, and corresponding pixel intensity values $z_i$. Our goal is to find numbers $A, B, C, D, E$, and $F$ such that
$$
z_i \approx A + B x_i + C y_i + D x_i^2 + E y_i^2 + F x_i y_i
$$
for $i = 1, \ldots, m$.
These equations can be written concisely using matrix notation as 
$$
X \beta \approx z,
$$
where
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2 & y_1^2 & x_1 y_1 \\
\vdots & & & & & \vdots \\
1 & x_m & y_m & x_m^2 & y_m^2 & x_m y_m\\
 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad \beta = \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \\ E \\ F \end{bmatrix}, \quad \text{and} \quad z = \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ \vdots \\ z_m \end{bmatrix}.
$$
We choose the vector $\beta$ to minimize $L(\beta) = \frac12 \| X \beta - z \|_2^2$.
This is a standard least squares problem, and we can solve it by setting the gradient of $L$ equal to $0$, which yields the so-called "normal equations":
$$
\nabla L(\beta) = X^T(X \beta - z) = 0 \implies X^T X \beta = X^T z.
$$
Note that $X^T X$ is a $6 \times 6$ matrix. We can solve this linear system of equations to obtain $\beta$.